# Pass one string from one frame to another

Tags: java, string, swing

I have a string in one frame named uname.

```
uname = usrNameTxt.getText();
char[] pword = pwordTxt.getPassword();
String password = new String(pword);
```

and pointed that to the next frame by

```
 this.dispose();
 new SectionsFclty(uname).setVisible(true);
```

and in my another one (shown below) frame want the String uname...

```
  public SectionsFclty() {
    initComponents();   
}

 public SectionsFclty(String uname) {
    initComponents();
    jLabelUsername.setText(uname);
}
```

But in my second frame (SectionsFclty.java) error comes in

```
  private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelUsername = new javax.swing.JLabel();..............

 }  // shows an error now
```

following error

```
  error: illegal start of expression
private void initComponents() {
            new SectionsFclty().setVisible(true);
```

required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error it shows?

Comment: You should always copy/paste the exact error message.

Comment: edited my qstn just check it

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the constructor with a `String` parameter.

```
SectionsFclty fclt = new SectionsFclty(uname);
fclt.setVisible(true);
```

Using two lines is not a strict requirement, but it helps seeing where errors happen. Chaining can be convenient and makes the code shorter, but at least as long as you are a beginner, try to keep things simple.

I do not recommend making `uname` static. Static is not usually needed, and tends to cause more problems than it solves.